# List all the posts in category from Multi dimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I would like to list all post under their various categories
I have multi dimensional array like this:

```
$categories = [

 ['category_name' => 'Book Category', 'post_title' => 'book 1'],
 ['category_name' => 'Book Category', 'post_title' => 'book 2'],

 ['category_name' => 'Shoe Category', 'post_title' => 'shoe 1'],
 ['category_name' => 'Shoe Category', 'post_title' => 'shoe 2'],

]
```

I want to list the categories and post title as follows on the same page:

**Book Category:**

Book 1

Book 2

**Shoe Category**

Shoe 1

Shoe 2

There are a lot of similar posts on here but they are too specific to various PHP frameworks which are not helpful in my case of Core PHP. I have tried this

```
foreach ($categories as $category) {
echo $category['category_name"] . "<br>";
echo $category['post_title"] . "<br>";
}
```

But I get something like this instead:

**Book Category**

Book 1

**Book Category**

Book 2

**Shoe Category**

Shoe 1

**Shoe Category**

Shoe 2

Not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this?

```
$printable_arr = [];
foreach($categories as $category) {
    $printable_arr[$category['category_name']][] = $category['post_title'];
}

// Now the array $printable_arr will have the items categorised. You can use the php functions to manipulate the array, or print the results as needed.
// For example:
foreach ($printable_arr as $category => $item)
{
  echo "<h1>$category</h1><br/>";
  echo implode("<br/>",$item);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. This is wow. But it just prints the array instead.  I would the plain readable text printed rather, not the code

Comment: You can use the PHP functions to access the elements in the array. I have edited my answer. Please check @Eli

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can build nested array first using [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) and then display it as you wish:

```
$nested = array_reduce($categories, function ($carry, $item) {
    $carry[$item['category_name']][] = $item['post_title'];

    return $carry;
}, []);
```

Then you can use nested `foreach`:

```
foreach ($nested as $category => $titles) {
    echo "$category:\n";

    foreach ($titles as $title) {
        echo "\t$title\n";
    }
}
```

Here is [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4606a62e1cba40da76aec749ff4121f828a4103e).

Or use [`RecursiveIteratorIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php):

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveArrayIterator($nested),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
);    

foreach ($iterator as $key => $value) {
    if ($iterator->getDepth() == 0) {
        echo "{$key}:\n";
    } else {
        echo "\t$value\n";
    }
}
```

Here is [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/745a3f85bc0cd282bc35acfb84d19b9f9fe562b4).

Comment: how do i get it to write human readable text instead of printing the array? Like this : 

Book Category:

Book 1

Book 2

Shoe Category

Shoe 1

Shoe 2

Comment: @ElizabethKof, well, I don't know the exact format you want, but you can try the demo I have updated.

Comment: Thank you @sevavietl, Your code works perfectly. Only that it so advanced that I find it difficult to expand on it in my project. I am a beginner. Well, I will keep learning PHP. I thought I had the basis to be able to do stuff but I am wrong

Answer (score 1):

This should rearrange your array into $category_array = [ 'category_name1' => array['title1','title2'], 'category_name2' => array['title1','title2'] ]

```
foreach ($categories as $category) {
  $category_array[$category['category_name']][] = $category['post_title'];
}
```

This will check if the category name has already been printed and print the array of values associated with category_name

```
$old_key = null;
foreach ($category_array as $key=>$value) {
  if ($key !== $old_key) {
    echo $key . '<br>';
    $old_key = $key;
  }
  if ($key === $old_key) {
    foreach ($value as $v) {
      echo $v . '<br>';
    }
  }
}
```

This is not fast due to all of the nested foreach and if statements, but it should get you what you want.

Comment: thanks for replying. Please what is the name of function for the way you rearranged the array? I would like to research about it and learn more. I mean what should I type in Google in order to learn more about how to do this `$category_array[$category['category_name']][] = $category['post_title'];`

Comment: There's no official name for it as far as I as I can recall. In a nutshell, it's taking a known array or object and saying $new_array[$key][] = $value so every time a certain $key comes up, it adds the $value to the new [$key][] array.

Comment: thank you very much for the info. I appreciate your time.

Comment: No problem :) just a note that someone will likely point out not to use comments to say thanks even though I appreciate it :). Also, codereview.se is great if you want to check if there are any ways to improve a working program. Cheers!